# CSS image object-fit transition how-to

Tags: image, css-transitions

img object-fit transition from cover to fit is not working for me -- is this not yet supported by modern browsers, or error on my part.

Usage pattern like so, using tailwind (other props removed to focus on relevant)

```
<img
   src={ctx.activeUrl}
   className={clsx("transition duration-300 ease-in-out", fit)}
/>
```

`fit` is react state that let's me toggle between fit and cover, and expecting to have smooth transition between fit and cover states, but no such luck :-( Any help much appreciated!